# How to stop Visual Studio 11 Beta async action methods from hanging

Tags: visual-studio, asynchronous, visual-studio-2012

Under Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview, async action methods worked correctly without issue. After installing Visual Studio 11 Beta, those same async action methods now cause the page to hang indefinitely.

```
public class HomeController : AsyncController {
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index() {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Change the action back to synchronous  and it works without hanging.

```
public class HomeController : Controller {
    public ActionResult Index() {
        return View();
    }
}
```

This blog post (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/03/10277166.aspx) makes me think the problem has to do with the beta however, the site is built targeting .NET Framework 4.5, not 4.0 so presumably it should work.

"This means that while you can absolutely use Visual Studio 11 Beta to build apps that use async/await with .NET 4.5, you are currently unable to use Visual Studio 11 Beta to build apps that use async/await against .NET 4, Silverlight 5, etc., since the compilers in Visual Studio 11 Beta are expecting differently shaped types than those in the existing AsyncCtpLibrary* DLLs."

Any suggestions on where to look for a fix?

Comment: There are some MS personnel on SO, but the Async team mostly hangs out on the [official forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/async/threads). I would recommend asking there.

Comment: I cross-posted there. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Stephen Troub](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/stephen%20toub%20-%20msft/?ws=usercard-mini) from Microsoft followed up and provided a workaround. You can see his post [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/async/thread/558d9dfb-c6c4-4440-a755-4d8f2d99b71c). In summary:

> there is a known bug in ASP.NET MVC in the .NET 4.5 Beta that results
>   in this issue when the async method completes synchronously.  Until a
>   fix is available, a simple workaround is to add "await Task.Yield();"
>   as the first line of the async method, forcing it to complete
>   asynchronously.  For this to work correctly, you also need to ensure
>   you're using the new SynchronizationContext supplied by ASP.NET in
>   .NET 4.5, which means ensuring you have the line:

```
<add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
```

> In the appSettings section of your configuration file.